# Get three values from the set of objects

Tags: javascript, object

after attempting multiple things I have come to the conclusion that I might just not be looking at this the right way. So I have decided to ask here.

I am trying to get the `_id` of the user, and inside of that object there is also a `visits` tab which I need the `postId` and the `visitCount`.

These are my attempts:

```
this.analyticsService.getClicks();
    this.userClicksSub = this.analyticsService
      .getUserAnalyticsClicks()
      .subscribe((userClicks: Clicks[]) => {
        this.userClicks = userClicks;
        console.log(this.userClicks);
        // const visits = this.userClicks['visits'];
        // console.log(visits);
      //   for (const item of this.userClicks) {
      //      const visits = item.visitCount;
      //      const visits = item.visitCount['visits'];
      //      const visits = item['visits'];
      //      const postId = visits[i]['postId'];
      //     console.log(item['visitCount']);
      //  }
        // this.userId.push(this.userClicks);
        // console.log(this.userId);
        // console.log(this.userId.user[1]);
        // console.log(this.userClicks.user.user); //
        // console.log('test', this.userClicks[2]);
});
```

That `console.log(this.userClicks);` gives me this:

[image]

Struggling to access the users visits tab values.

I have this table which needs to be populated by the results:

`<th>{{ userclick._id }}</th>`

`<th>{{ userclick.postId }}</th>`

`<th>{{ userclick.visitCount }}</th>`

It will loops through the results and display them accordingly.

Comment: which user? There are 3??

Comment: Yeah eventually there will be loads, I just need to extract the users which have visited a page etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you just need to feel a little more comfort in diving through nested values!

There are two things which can nest further values: `Array`, and `Object`. When diving into an `Array`, you provide a numeric index: `arr[12]` will result in the 13th value in the `Array` (because of 0-based indexing). When diving into an `Object` you can often use dot-notation: `obj.innerProperty` gives you `obj`'s "innerProperty".

The root object you're dealing with, `this.userClicks`, is an `Array`. So if you want to access an inner item you need to specify a numeric index; e.g. `this.userClicks[2]`. I see that you've tried to do `this.userClicks['visits']`, which won't work because `this.userClicks` doesn't have a "visits" property; intead *each item within `this.userClicks`* has the "visits" property you're looking for.

If you want to apply the same operation to all items within `this.userClicks` you need to use some kind of loop.

E.g. a simple for-loop:

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.userClicks.length; i++) {
  let currentClick = this.userClicks[i];
  // do something with `currentClick`
}
```

E.g. a declarative style `forEach`:

```
this.userClicks.forEach(currentClick => {
  // do something with `currentClick`
});
```

Comment: When I log the currentClick, it repeats the values x3 since there are 3 different objects, is this normal?

Comment: Don't think of it as "repeating" a value 3 times! Instead, think of `this.userClicks` as a single "thing" which contains 3 more things. I think you are expecting `this.userClicks` to be a representation of a single "click", when in fact it is a representation of a SERIES of clicks.

Comment: Okay, I see, so how can I save the three special values I need?

Comment: You're looking to get the "_id", "postId", and "visitCount". The issue is, there are several instances of each of these values: there are a series of "clicks", and for each "click" in that series, there are a series of "visits". Then, for each visit in *that* series are the 3 values you're looking for. You need to know the index of the click, and the index of the visit, to talk about a *specific* 3 values.

Comment: For example if you know `clickIndex` and `visitIndex` then you can say `let specificVisitOfSpecificClick = this.usersClicks[clickIndex].user.visits[visitIndex]`. Now you can talk about `specificVisitOfSpecificClick._id`, `specificVisitOfSpecificClick.visitCount`, etc.

Comment: This seems more complicated than I thought, to be honest, I will try to do what you have said, thanks for all your feedback.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179652/discussion-between-gershom-maes-and-andrew).

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate twice since there is a nested array

```
this.userClicks.forEach(function(item){
 item.user.visit.forEach(function(elem){
  console.log(elem.visitCount)
 })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop, you can use the following to solve your problem:

```
item.user.visit[whatever index you want]._id
```

Answer (score 0):

Try next:
`var infos = userClicks.map(user => user.visits.map(({_id, postId}) => ({id: _id, postId}))).reduce((result, currentValue) => result.concat(currentValue), []);`

infos.forEach(info => console.log(`<th>${info.id}</th><th>${info.postId}</th><th>${info.visitCount}</th>`))